# How to set up Cordova iOS build with GitHub Actions?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, continuous-integration, github-actions

[This guide](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/deploying-xcode-applications/installing-an-apple-certificate-on-macos-runners-for-xcode-development) goes good length in describing setting the environment up, however, I'm not in the clear whether `build.json` should be prepared set up for auto or manual profile management [[ref]](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/platforms/ios/#using-buildjson).

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @mikeysee yeah, we had to go for manual provisioning profile management